# How can I remove RAID 1 on Ubuntu 18.04 server to reclaim storage space?

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I have a server with raid1 set up, I want more memory by removing raid1 but I don't know enough to do this. Please provide commands that will allow me to delete the raid and get 2 disks separately.

```
root@nb0fd8f:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[1] nvme1n1p3[0]
      981406720 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [==>..................]  resync = 11.1% (108961728/981406720) finish=85.6min speed=169852K/sec
      bitmap: 8/8 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p4[1] nvme1n1p4[0]
      16068608 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 nvme1n1p2[0] nvme0n1p2[1]
      1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

```
root@nb0fd8f:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            32927088       0  32927088   0% /dev
tmpfs            6597988    7156   6590832   1% /run
/dev/md1       965875760 2817980 913971060   1% /
tmpfs           32989924       0  32989924   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           32989924       0  32989924   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         84096   84096         0 100% /snap/core/4327
/dev/md0         1014680  157996    787924  17% /boot
/dev/loop1        101632  101632         0 100% /snap/core/10958
tmpfs            6597984       0   6597984   0% /run/user/0
```

```
root@nb0fd8f:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    82M  1 loop  /snap/core/4327
loop1         7:1    0  99.2M  1 loop  /snap/core/10958
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0     5M  0 part
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0 936.1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0   936G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme0n1p4 259:5    0  15.3G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0  15.3G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
nvme1n1     259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:6    0     5M  0 part
├─nvme1n1p2 259:7    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0  1023M  0 raid1 /boot
├─nvme1n1p3 259:8    0 936.1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0   936G  0 raid1 /
└─nvme1n1p4 259:9    0  15.3G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0  15.3G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu Server in a production environment, then you should have some recent backups of your data. The fastest and least frustrating way to change RAID1 to independent storage devices in this scenario would be to reinstall the operating system, then restore from the most recent backup.

If you're running Ubuntu Server in a development environment, then backups may be less important as everything may be set up to be ephemeral, allowing for quick refreshes. The fastest and least frustrating way to change RAID1 to independent storage devices in this scenario would be to reinstall the operating system, then restore the development environment using the configuration scripts you likely have.

If you're running Ubuntu Server in a situation where backups have never been performed and are *way* off the radar, then the fastest and least frustrating way to add storage would be to keep the RAID1 configuration — as it was likely configured RAID1 for a reason — and install some additional storage devices, be they spinning disks or solid state devices. From there you can mount the new devices to specific locations and manage the data accordingly.

These really are the simplest options. While it is *technically* possible to do what you're asking, it's not something that should be done without a very solid understanding of how file systems work, how file systems break, and how file systems are fixed.